# i cant get the index value of selected item in listbox in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, listbox, python-3.6

I am working on Tkinter Listbox with the database , i can't get the index value of the selected item in list box

```
def admin_get():
    global selection
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry('500x400')
    listbox1 = Listbox(win,selectmode=SINGLE,width=60)
    listbox1.place(x=50,y=100)

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM admin")
    for i in cursor:
        listbox1.insert(END,i)
        #print(i)

    button = Button(win, text='change state', command=state)
    button.place(x=90, y=300)
    selection = listbox1.curselection(ACTIVE)
    win.mainloop()
def state():
    #messagebox.showinfo("alert",'Changed')
    print(selection)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function listbox1.curselection() takes no arguments.
According to it's documentation it

> [r]eturns a tuple containing the line numbers of the selected element or elements, counting from 0. If nothing is selected, returns an empty tuple.

Additional:
You can detect, if the tuple is empty with

```
if selected:
    #some code
```

The code will only be executed if an item of the listbox is selected.